# unit test error because connection string retunes null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

im trying to write a unit test,i have copied my app setting in my test project it contains my connection string to mongo db but once i run the test i get  System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString'),

here is my test:

```
 public Mock<IDataService> mock = new Mock<IDataService>();

    [Fact]
        void TestCase1()
        {

        var stocksTemp = new List<StockData>{

                    new StockData {
                        BaseCurrency = "EUR",
                        NumberOfShares = 150,
                        Ticker = "KINV"
                    }
                };

        var tt = new PortfolioData()
        {
            CurrentTotalValue = 200121,
            Stocks = stocksTemp
        };

        var nn = new PortfolioData();

       var result= mock.Setup(p => p.GetPortfolio("61377666d24fd78398a5a558")).ReturnsAsync(nn);

        Assert.True(tt.Equals(result));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does `DataService.GetPortfolio` do internally?

Comment: DataService is where i have written my code to contact db and Get data

Comment: Right, but can you share that code in your post? It would be helpful for us to see what that class looks like.

Comment: what exactly is this test supposed to do?  Focus on that. Why are you looking at connection strings and appSettings when you want to write a unit test? You've gone down the wrong path, what you are trying to write is not a unit test but something that will not help you write better code.

Comment: This is not a unit test, but it is instead an integration test. Your `DataService` is essentially a wrapper around MongoDB, and the MongoDB client is already thoroughly tested internally. If you really *need* to test this class, I recommend checking out some tools such as Mongo2Go.

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu you mean to do a unittest i dont need a appsetting,thats fine i removed it,but what about my controller,should i instantiate my controller inside unittest?

Comment: no, keep your controllers thin, move the logic to a library and test things that way. The fact that you need to instantiate a controller for  a test should tell you that you're not doing enough separation of concerns. Things get easier when you do that

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu i updated my question,could you please take a look?the setup part is where i should get the test result?still getting the connectionstring error but at least i change my test flow

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you copied the appsetting file to Unit Test project but you didn't read anything from that file. In AspNetCore project, they have written code to read the values from appsetting but that not the case for Unit Test projects. You need to manually read it.

```cs
// Packages: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json and Namespace: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
IPortfolioDatabaseSetting _dataBseMock = config.GetSection("SectionName")
                                        .Get<PortfolioDatabaseSetting>() // Use actual class not interface
```

If you don't need to use appsetting then can direct create a new instance of PortfolioDatabaseSetting and add connection string directly to the property

```cs
IPortfolioDatabaseSetting _dataBseMock = new PortfolioDatabaseSetting { ConnectionString = "YouActualConnectionString" }
```

Comment: I need to write it in my unittest project?shoul i copy the app setting in my unittest project as well?

Comment: @masali Yes, if not you can direct create a new instance of `PortfolioDatabaseSetting` and add connection string directly to the property

Comment: @masali I assumed that you already copied when you said "i have copied my app setting in my test project"